# GitHub Actions with Java to build automatically Linux packages

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, debian-packaging

### Introduction

I am currently creating a Java Maven project and wanted to build the project in a Linux package.

I found some links to build a Debian packages :

- https://fracpete.github.io/debian-maven-plugin/usage.html
- https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/building-debian-packages-in-java/

### Problematic

But I was wondering if it is possible to automate building a Linux package (Debian, Ubuntu Fedora..), with GitHub Actions.

I wanted to automate this with GitHub actions, for example when we create a release in GitHub repository, GitHub actions automatically add `.deb` `.rpm` in the release files.

### Question

Do you know if there is a GitHub Actions to do this? or do you know how to do it?

Comment: Use [rpm-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Have I said so.. you can of course the debian one...